# DB2 - SQL Syntax to generate string with custom length of one character

Tags: sql, db2

I have a database table with the following state:

```
Id           Animal     Length      Filler 
------------ --------- ----------- ------------- 
1            DOG      1                         
2            DOG      3                         
3            DOG      8                         
4            DOG      4                         
5            DOG      8
```

Scenario: I try to generate string by the length of the length field in the database column with the same character (let's say 'x'). So the filler for Id 1 should be 'x'.

This should work in a generic way. 
So if the length is 4, it should create the string 'xxxx'. 
If the length is 8 'xxxxxxxx' etc.

Needed for: It should update the value, in case this is a dog. I'm familiar with updating and selecting by restricting by the where condition, however I'm not aware how to create string only containing the same character for the amount of another selected column.

Comment: Perhaps `repeat('x', length)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `repeat()` function:

```
update tablename
set Filler = repeat('x', length)
where Animal = 'DOG'
```

However, I'd rather have a view to avoid data inconsistency if the length value is updated, but not Filler. Or, at least use triggers.

Comment: Thanks, this answer is correct. I searched for the function repeat. The function can also take the data of a column as input parameter, so it fulfilled my use case.

Answer (score 1):

LPAD function should do, e.g:

```
db2 "values lpad('',8,'x')"

1       
--------
xxxxxxxx

  1 record(s) selected.
```

example

```
db2 "create table animals(id int, animal varchar(10), len int, filter varchar(10))"

db2 "insert into animals(id, animal, len) values (1, 'DOG', 1) "
db2 "insert into animals(id, animal, len) values (2, 'DOG', 3) "
db2 "insert into animals(id, animal, len) values (3, 'DOG', 8) "
db2 "select * from animals"

ID          ANIMAL     LEN         FILTER    
----------- ---------- ----------- ----------
          1 DOG                  1 -         
          2 DOG                  3 -         
          3 DOG                  8 -         

  3 record(s) selected.

db2 "update animals set filter = lpad('',len,'x')"
db2 "select * from animals"

ID          ANIMAL     LEN         FILTER    
----------- ---------- ----------- ----------
          1 DOG                  1 x         
          2 DOG                  3 xxx       
          3 DOG                  8 xxxxxxxx  

  3 record(s) selected.
```